# Function checking if no two pieces are on the same diagonal (java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, function, boolean

I am trying to create a program that prints out all solution `1 <= n <= 13` of the n-queens problem. The program will read an integer `n` from the command line indicating the size of the Queens problem to solve. For example, if `n = 5` it would print out

```
(1, 3, 5, 2, 4)
(1, 4, 2, 5, 3)
(2, 4, 1, 3, 5)
(2, 5, 3, 1, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
(3, 5, 2, 4, 1)
(4, 1, 3, 5, 2)

(4, 2, 5, 3, 1)
(5, 2, 4, 1, 3)
(5, 3, 1, 4, 2)
```

Currently, I am just stuck on one function of my program. I need to create a method that will return true if the permutation represented by (A[1], A[2], A[3], ..., A[n]) places no two queens (chess pieces) on the same diagonal, and will return false otherwise. To check if two queens at (A[i], i) and (A[j], j) lie on the same diagonal, I need to check if the horizontal distance apart is the same as their vertical distance apart.

The function is called `isSolution()` and should compare each pair of queens at most once. If a pair is found on the same diagonal, do no further comparisons and return false. If all `n(n-1) / 2` comparisons are performed without finding a diagonal attack, return true.

```
static boolean isSolution(int[] A){
    blah blah blah
}
```

I already have a function that produces all permutations of a set in lexicographic order, and its final permutation to its original state.

What goes within the `isSolution()` function? I'm extremely lost, anything would help, even pseudocode that outlines the body of `isSolution()`.

Things I do know: `i` and `j` are the horizontal and vertical distances between two pieces. I need to make a pair of for loops that make it so it goes through every `n(n-1) / 2` comparisons. "`i`" and "`j`" should be the differences between the array indexes and the array elements, respectively. I also need to use `Math.abs` to the differences to be safe. So in the for loops, initialize `i` and `j` as the differences I mentioned, then set up an if that checks `if i==j` that returns false. If all the comparisons are made and false wasn't returned, then return true.

Comment: After "Things I do know" you seem to have an outline of an attempt at solving the problem. Did you try to write the code for this? Did you step through an example to see if it would work?

Answer (score 6):

`(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)` is 1 or -1 if x1,y1 and x2,y2 is diagonal

it is basically angle of line between two coordinates

Comment: which is equivalent to `abs(y1-y2) == abs(x1-x2)`. This form is more explicitly related to the fact that the x-axis distance is equals to the y-axis distance. (and avoid division, floats etc...)

Answer (score 3):

The rejection test expresses that the horizontal and vertical distances are equal,

```
Abs(A[J] - A[I]) == Abs(J - I)
```

and you will try every distinct `(I, J)` pair. If you make sure that `I < J`, the second `Abs` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

2 elements are on the same diagonal if their sum or difference is the same or mod difference is the same

if a1(i,j) and b1(k,l) are the element positions:
if  |l-j| = |i-k| they are on the same diagonal

Another way is to check i+j=l+k upward diagonal like / or i-j=k-l -- downward diagonal like \ -- if you need the direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly more efficient solution:

Initialize an array `D[-n+1..+n-1]` to all `false`, then set all entries `D[A[i] - i]` to `true`. If an entry is found to be already `true`, you detected an alignment. (`D` marks occupancy of every diagonal.)

Repeat this with `D[A[i] + i]` for the other diagonal direction (using `D[0..2n-2]`).

This is `O(n)`.

On the 13x13 chessboard, this will require 25 clears, then 13 test-and-sets, twice (a bitwise implementation could be beneficial). Compare to the "pairs" solution, which costs 78 evaluations of the alignment test.